# Does dragon maturity (past juvenile) have any effect on breeding?

Tags: dragonvale

As I level my dragons, I've ended up with multiple individuals of different levels. Past juvenile I can use any of them to breed. Does a different level have any effect on breeding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated with latest information

From what has been read/told/seen with my own eyes, the dragon order has no beaering on the type of dragon you will get. However with a recent patch ([1.13.0](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Game_Updates)) it has been stated that breeding higher level dragons (15+) will increase the chance of getting a rare dragon from the pairing.

You can check out my question and its answers for more information on breeding chances here: [What are the chances of breeding a type of dragon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59799/what-are-the-chances-of-breeding-a-type-of-dragon)

Comment: As part of a [recent update](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Game_Updates), I believe this answer is now out of date.  Care to edit?

Answer (score 0):

*At level 10 they are more likely to breed rare dragon types like rainbow and sun and such. For normal combo's, there's really no point. They do give you more money past juvenile though, so I always get my dragons to lvl 10 right away.* 
EDIT: This seems to be completely wrong, read the fourth comment. Sorry.

Comment: Is there any evidence that supports this? Seems possible but the Wiki makes lots of claims like this that don't seem to pan out. I'll agree that making everything lvl 10 regardless is a good way to go

Comment: I would likewise be interested in seeing any evidence of this as that would be very awesome, but everything points to random right now.

Comment: I read something somewhere a while ago XD Besides that I didn't get either of my rainbows until all dragons were level 10 (and therefore the breeded ones), and I only did that at lvl 20, before that having them just at 7 to breed with. I'll see if I can pull up where I read that before, sorry I don't have a reference right now.

Comment: Wow... I'm sorry.. I'm wrong. Evidence I'm  now finding seems to point against me... XD That's embarrassing. I'll post where I'm finding some evidence now. "Q: Do the levels of each dragon matter in breeding?

A: After the dragons reach level 4 and are able to breed, their levels most likely do not matter in determining breeding outcomes." http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ                          "There's been no indication that either your level, or your dragons level effects the chance of you getting rare dragons." http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/643337-dragonvale/62078480

Comment: It happens.  +1 for double checking your answer.

Comment: @Zeff520 Ah well, Thanks for the information and we can keep on hoping :)